# Sends two bytes when data is over 7bit?

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I have a strange behaviour of QSerialPort in QT Creator when I write down bytes, which are bigger than the ASCII number 127. Somehow It always sends the number 194 first, then comes the number I actually want to transmit. So for example for the number 150, it sends [194,150].

The serial interface is correctly initialized with 8bit data, so this should work just fine:

```
serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);
serialPort->setPortName(str);
serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
```

The data is written like this:

```
serialPort->write(QString(QChar(150)).toStdString().c_str());
```

Anyone an idea, what could cause this problem?

Comment: That's not C but C++. Maybe the value 150 is treated as some multibyte/unicode character. Looks like UTF8 encoding. You could try printing the length of the string before sending it to the UART.

Comment: Yes, it is C++, did somehow missclick. Well, serialPort->write() gives back 2 for numbers bigger 127 and else it gives back 1. QString(QChar(150)).length() is 1 for all numbers.

Comment: I didn't ask about output of `write()` but about input to `write`. What do you feed into it? As you use `c_str` it seems to expect a `char*` Did you try feeding something like `char test[]="\x96";` into it?

Comment: If `QString.Length` is 1, maybe you get UTF encoding during `toStdString` or `c_str`. Check `strlen(QString(QChar(150)).toStdString().c_str())`.

Comment: strlen(QString(QChar(150)).toStdString().c_str()) gives back 2, so indeed this is somehow handled like a signed char. What should I use instead for conversion?

Comment: Ok, I got it, I use now .toLatin1(), otherwise it indeed converts to UTF

Comment: If you didn't start out with the idea that the text needed to be encoded as ISO 8859-1, are you sure that you should end up there? This is something that the receiver needs to understand/agree to, also.  (BTW—You can write an answer yourself and accept it when you think it is the best, sufficient answer.)